# Passing a FacesMessage to the next page

Tags: jsf-2

I am looking for a graceful JSF way to do this and was wondering if there was any commonly accepted practice for doing this.

When I navigate from one page to another, I want the new page to show a FacesMessage in a **h:message** component (actually **p:message** but it should be the same thing) that was transmitted from the last page.

So for example, if a user clicks a "Create Document" button it navigates to a new page on success, and shows the success message on the new page.  I want all my data-base changing operations to behave that way.

It seems that the **FacesContext** clears all messages on the navigation, so my closest solution looks like this:

1. Store the FacesMessage object in the session bean.
2. Create a method **checkMessage** in the message bean that calls **FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(..)** and removes the message from the message bean.
3. Put a EL reference to **checkMessage** in the destination page.
4. Put a **p:message** in the destination page.

This seems a bit forced -- is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Faces messages are indeed request scoped.

Just make use of the new JSF 2.0 Flash scope: [`Flash#setKeepMessages()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setKeepMessages%28boolean%29):

```
context.addMessage(clientId, message);
context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
// ...
```

This has only one caveat in the current Mojarra 2.1.13 release: the redirect has to take place in the same "folder" in the URL. This is fixed in the shortly upcoming 2.1.14. See also [issue 2136](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2136).

Comment: will I just tried that and it works like a charm.  Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

http://ocpsoft.org/java/persist-and-pass-facesmessages-over-page-redirects/

http://balusc.blogspot.se/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html

Maybe one of those will help?

Comment: Both authors are great contributors imo.